# How to get value of android:targetPackage in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, robotium

From my Junit test code, how do I access the value of android:targetPackage in Manifest within the Junit test app?

I am trying to extract "com.mycompany.mytestapp".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.mycompany.mytestapp" />
...  
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `PackageManager.getPackageInfo(String packageName, int flags)` with flag  `GET_INSTRUMENTATION`.

This will give you a `PackageInfo` object that has a field called `instrumentation`
There you will find any <instrumentation> tags information, including `targetPackage`

Comment: PackageInfo packageInfo =         inst.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(inst.getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_INSTRUMENTATION);
String targetPackageName =     packageInfo.instrumentation[0].targetPackage;

Answer (score 0):

Works now. Did the following. Thank you!

PackageInfo packageInfo = inst.getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(inst.getContext().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_INSTRUMENTATION);
   String targetPackageName = packageInfo.instrumentation[0].targetPackage;